# Delete function in wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress

In wp admin page all delete functions are not working,
Such as plugin delete, page delete, post delete etc.. are not working and also there is no errors displayed on clicking the delete option.

Comment: Enable `wp_debug` to show error message.

Comment: the plugin delete is an ajax delete option it does not omits an error, i also enabled  wp_debug

Comment: No.In wp ajax process with PHP and `wp_debug` to set show errors of php in wp.If you endabled `wp_debug` you can open your browser developer tools and select tab `Network` -> `XHR` to show ajax result.